# Is it possible to add smooch as a tab in the BottomNavigationView

Tags: smooch

I´m trying to integrate Smooch chat in my Android application, using it as a tab in the bottom navigation. Is it possible to embed it in some way? If not, what do you recommend?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

The SDK doesn't support the use of `ConversationFragment` on its own at the moment.